# Lombok with Maven on Mac

Tags: macos, maven, java-8, lombok

I am using Java 8 on OSX. I have the lombok.jar in classpath and I have the following dependency in maven.

```
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.14.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

When I try to build the code from maven, I get compilation issues :

```
 mvn clean install
 ...error: cannot find symbol
 [ERROR] symbol:   variable log
 error: cannot find symbol
 [ERROR] symbol:   method getMinLevel()
```

These are methods/injected dependencies by Lombok not found at the build time. I am not sure what else is required to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Lombok 1.14.0 is probably the problem. Version 1.14.2 fixes some of the problems, or gives information for better insight. Full Disclosure: I am one of the lombok core developers.

Answer (score 0):

lombok writes code at compile time by inserting it directly in your class file.

You must probably have some @xxx lombok logging annotation set, which apparently compiles to another version of the log library than you have in your maven path.

See the dependencies with `mvn dependency:tree` or `mvn dependency:list`to pinpoint your compile version..

I assume you have embedded lombok in your IDE? And it works there, you say? Are you using the same classpath as maven generates (i.e. using a maven plugin for your IDE)?

Comment: I have run lombok.jar for Eclipse, I get the same error inside IDE also.

Comment: Which log are annotation are you using CommonsLog, Log, Log4j, Log4j2, Slf4j, XSlf4j?

Comment: No, Lombok doesn't work with the class file, it modifies the compiler's AST. Lombok in Netbeans works by hooking into `javac`, in Eclipse it works similarly, but the implementation differs and it needs to be mentioned as agent in `eclipse.ini`. So speaking about IDE in general doesn't help. @Ved: Verify if really nothing works (`@Getter`, `@AllArgsContructor`, ...) or if there's a problem with a specific annotation. I'm using Lombok with both Eclipse and gradle and both work fine.

Comment: @maaartinus: I oversimplified, sorry. Given that the error exist in mvn alone, there is no reason to suspect the IDE and the agent stuff. Ved: The feature page (http://projectlombok.org/features/Log.html) doesn't  hint at using a method called getMinLevel(). Can you elaborate and if possibly narrow a use-case down and show it to us. I'm sure we can fix it, but we need more clues

Comment: I'm not the OP, I just wanted to make it a bit clearer. I guess `getMinLevel` is simply `@Getter minLevel`, i.e., completely unrelated to logging (AFAIK there's nothing like this in any logging framework). I'm just guessing.

Comment: yes the logger is slf4j and getMinLevel is Getter minLevel. I tried this on Windows and lombok works perfectly fine. I think this is something very specific to MacOSX classpath and lombok.jar